# Single TCP connection for a symmetrical communication

Tags: c#, wcf

I would like to implement a WCF service that allows two nodes to communicate in both directions in a symmetrical way. In particular, here are the requirements:

- I don't need a request/reply protocol, but I need callbacks for asynchronous replies;
- a single TCP connection must be established between the two nodes;
- when the connection is established, the communication must be symmetrical (each of the two nodes can send requests to the other one, each of the two nodes can receive a reply from the other one) in the single TCP connection.

As a consequence, I think I should use the NetTcpBinding and use the same interface for both the service and for the callback by using inheritance.

```
interface ICommonInterface
{
    void Request(string dataRequest);
    void Reply(string dataReply);
    void Disconnect();  // both nodes must be able to close the TCP connection
}

[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required, CallbackContract = typeof(IMyServiceCallback))]
interface IMyService : ICommonInterface
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, IsInitiating = true, IsTerminating = false)]
    void Connect();

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = false)]
    void Request(string dataRequest);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = false)]
    void Reply(string dataReply);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = true)]
    void Disconnect();
}

interface IMyServiceCallback : ICommonInterface
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = false)]
    void Request(string dataRequest);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = false)]
    void Reply(string dataReply);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = true)]
    void Disconnect();
}
```

Could this kind of implementation work?
Are there better alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

MSDN has a nice async TCP tutorial:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5w7b7x5f(v=vs.71).aspx

If you understand callbacks and basic thread, it'll be fairly simple.

Comment: I forgot to say that I should use WCF.

Comment: ahh.. Sorry then, I'm not sure as I haven't worked with it. I'll vote up your question.   Good luck